# How efficient iOS file system in dealing with large number of files in single folder

Tags: ios, filesystems

If I have large number of files (n x 100K individual files) what would be most efficient way to store them in iOS file system (from speed of access to the file by path point of view)? Should I dump them all in single folder or break them in multilevel folder hierarchy.

Basically this breaks in three questions:

1. does file access time depend on number of "sibling" files (I think
   answer is yes. If I am correct file names are organized into b-tree
   so it should be O(log n))?
2. how expensive is traversing from one folder to another along the
   path (is it something like m * O( log nm ) - where m is number of
   components in the path and nm is number of "siblings" at each path
   component )?
3. What gets cached at file system level to make above assumptions incorrect?

It would be great if some one had direct experience with this kind of problem and can share some real life results.

You comments will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like it might provide relevant, hard data:

### File System vs Core Data: the image cache test

http://biasedbit.com/blog/filesystem-vs-coredata-image-cache

Conclusion:

> File system cache is, as expected, faster. Core Data falls shortly behind when storing (marginally slower) but load times are way higher when performing single random accesses.
>
> For such a simple case Core Data functionality really doesn't pay up, so stick to the file system version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should store everything is a one folder and create a hash table which include key (file name) and value (source path) pare.By creating hash table complexity with be constant log(1) and this will speed up your process as well.

Comment: I am not sure it will help me much.  I have no issue with creating file path.  My question was how to organize my files to make sure that I can access them as fast as possible - how to make it easier for iOS to resolve the path.

It could work if somehow I could get Node ID (CNID) for the file and then if I could open file by CNID (which I think is O(1)), but I can not find any public APIs which provide access to Node ID.

Answer (score 0):

The file system is not an optimal database.  With that many thousands of files, you should consider using Core Data, or other database instead to store the name and contents of each file.

Comment: Actually, I am using Core Data right now and totally unimpressed with performance.  It takes forever to delete 100K or records. I hope that  with file system it is going to be much faster (deleting). If I can access files reasonably fast, I will be more then happy to ditch Core Data.

Comment: How are your delete rules setup? Cascading deletes can take "forever".